# How to create water with ripples in custom places for top down game in Unity?

Tags: unity, 2d, water

I want to make topdown row boat game with Unity. I want graphics to be simple (sprited), but the water must be "very nice" and realistic and it should reflect movement in it (paddles and boat movement maybe minor things like rain).

I was satisfied by the look of water made from basic assets, but I don't know how to add ripples from boat and paddle bodies. (is it possible?).

Can I use this or any other free component for my purpose or should I write some sort of script for my very own water behavior somehow?

Examples of 2d water ripples i like:

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sC71DZO8rG8
- http://code.almeros.com/code-examples/water-effect-canvas

Comment: You may be able to get by with Unity's particle system. See this post that Gamasutra promoted on twitter earlier today for more info: http://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/RoqueRey/20150115/234209/Adding_static_water_with_pixel_art_and_3D.php

Comment: Could you show an example of what you mean by "very nice"? I'm wondering if what Ben Wyatt proposed is good enough for you, or if you want some kind of eulerian water calculations like in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jl54WZtm0QE

Comment: I would like something like these ripples: http://code.almeros.com/code-examples/water-effect-canvas/

Comment: Take a look at this: http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/graphics/x_water.htm
This is the how the example you mentioned works.

Comment: To do it properly youll need to take partial derivatives of the surface to refract and reflect

Comment: there are free source code here: http://unitycoder.com/blog/tag/waves/